# How to setup free jqGrid in Angular 2+

Tags: jquery, angular, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I've tried to follow some explanations in this site about installing free jqGrid, but with no success.

First I overwrited an example by Oleg in jsfiddle. This is what I did https://jsfiddle.net/m8ap1dkb/1/
(which works as expected)

Then pasted it in my angular project, but it doesn't seem to build. It shows up blank.

In Angular I installed free-jqGrid and jquery, using a static data for the grid.

HTML

```
<table id="grid"></table>
```

component.ts

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

ngOnInit() {
$( () => {
      "use strict";
      (<any>$("#grid")).jqGrid({... (as in fiddle)
```

The angular.json contains

```
"scripts": [
   ...
   "node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css",
   "node_modules/free-jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css"
 ],
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "node_modules/free-jqgrid/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js",
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
   "node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js",
   ...
 ]
```

If one can help, I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know exactly changes I did, but I got it resolved.

Use "declare var $: any;" instead of "import * as $ from 'jquery';", as mentioned in older posts.

But keep advised that I had tried it before creating this question, so maybe this is not the only thing to fix.

Also I deleted one line in scripts and reordened.

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js",
  "node_modules/free-jqgrid/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js",
  ...
]
```